# How to insert values using Joins in asp.net stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_HRM_Insert_VehicleAssign]
     @vehiclename varchar(50),
     @empname varchar(50),
     @updatedby varchar(50),
     @updatedon datetime
 AS 
 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO K_MasterEmpDetails ME 
     INNER JOIN K_HRM_Vehicle_Assign VA ON VA.[empname+id] = ME.Firstname +' '+ME.Lastname + ' - ' + ME.kjlid AS ME.Employee
     (VA.vehiclename, ME.Employee, VA.updatedby, VA.updatedon)
     VALUES (@vehiclename, @empname, @updatedby, GETDATE())
 END
```

I am getting an error near `ME`...please help me

Answer (score 2):

You can't use this syntax. Correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO Table
(COLUMNS)
VALUES
(value)
```

For correct insert into two tables you have to use transaction and insert into two table separately.

Answer (score 0):

You're syntactically wrong. The correct syntax is what user [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19832729/1439935) is basic
but you can use

```
Insert into Table 
select statement
```

It will select the rows based on condition then insert into table.
and in select statement you can use join.